# Build debian package without .orig file

Tags: linux, debian, software-packaging

I've created packages previously by using a Makefile, the command "dh_make --createorig", then adjusting files in the debian folder generated and finally using the debuild command to generate the .deb. That workflow is simple and works for me, but I was told to adjust it a little in a way that you could build the project from the sources without requiring the orig files and I'm unsure how to do it, but according to this (https://askubuntu.com/questions/17508/how-to-have-debian-packaging-generate-two-packages-given-an-upstream-source-arch) and this structure (http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~andrewsomething/imagination/debian/files) there must be a way. In my case I would have a folder with the sources and all of that and then a debian folder (generated with dh_make) but I'm unsure on how to avoid the debuild command to ask for the .orig files or if I should be using some other command for this.

Sorry for the superlong question, I think I provided all the relevant information, but I can clarify if anything is fuzzy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a Debian directory directly in the source package (ie you're packaging your own work, rather than from an upstream release) you could use the `--native` option to `dh_make`

Answer (score 5):

The difference is in the version number in the file `debian/changelog`.

If you use `1.2.3-1` it implied Debian build 1 of an upstream package 1.2.3 --- for which the build programs (`dpkg-buildpackage` and whichever wrappers on top) --- assume an `.orig.tar.gz` to exists.

But if you use `1.2.3` it will consider the package 'Debian native' and the archive is just a `.tar.gz` and not an `.orig.tar.gz`.

Now the choice should not be driven by your convenience alone. If this has an upstream source, use the first scheme.  If not, the second can be fine.  In the packages I maintain I have both but *way more* of the former.

Comment: I prefer this approach to getting the upstream orig version. ```perl -e "use Dpkg::Version; printf Dpkg::Version->new(\"${VERSION}\")->as_string(omit_epoch => 1, omit_revision => 1);"```

Comment: wow, how subtle is that build fix, thx xD

Answer (score 2):

I think the question was asked differently, it was somewhat clear that the project was upstream and it's probably not a good reason to change its format to `native`.

Currently I package some upstream python project, this exact same question came to my mind. Why isn't there any dh_* hook to overwrite in order to generate this origin tarball on the fly so you do not get bothered by:

`This package has a Debian revision number but there does not seem to be
an appropriate original tar file or .orig directory in the parent directory;`

for a start, I added a makefile to the project:

`# Makefile
VERSION:=$(shell dpkg-parsechangelog -S Version | sed -rne 's,([^-\+]+)+(\+dfsg)*.*,\1,p'i)
UPSTREAM_PACKAGE:=click_${VERSION}.orig.tar.gz
dpkg:
  tar cafv ../${UPSTREAM_PACKAGE} . --exclude debian --exclude .git
  debuild -uc -us
clean:
  rm -f ../${UPSTREAM_PACKAGE}
  debuild clean`

so a simple `make clean dpkg` was all it needed to build the package.
Now I think the question remains if someone has some bright idea how to insert the `tar` operation within the `debian/rules` so I could just call debuild -uc -us and it magically creates the `orig` tarball I would be awsome :)

Comment: You have to put the two --exclude parameters *before* the dot ".", otherwise the debian/ and .git/ folders will be included in the tar.gz.